# C++ Winmm PlaySound API Returning False And Not Playing Sound

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winmm

No compiler issues, No linker issues, all that happens when this program is ran the PlaySound function returns FALSE and doesn't play any sound at all,

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/670195970226651140/852503334505676820/unknown.png

As seen in the figure image above the directory is perfectly fine, I've ran this program on both Release, and Debug, Any help would be very much appreciated, the code is below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ThisFile;
    ThisFile.open("S:\\Visual Studio Projects\\KB\\A\\Test.wav");
    if (ThisFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "std::ifstream Success!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "std::ifstream Failure!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Begin Sound" << std::endl;
    BOOL PlaySoundReturn = PlaySound(L"S:\\Visual Studio Projects\\KB\\A\\Test.wav", NULL, SND_SYNC | SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT);
    if (PlaySoundReturn == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `_UNICODE` defined in your project? Does it work if you change `L"RandomSound.wav"` to `"RandomSound.wav"`?

Comment: This is C++ code that compiles. Consequently the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol must be defined. The issue is, that you are using a relative path (most likely). Using a relative path is always an error. Use a fully qualified pathname instead.

Comment: Are you able to open the file using standard C++ I/O functions, such as [`ifstream::open`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open)? If not, then your project's working directory is probably not what you expect. You can use [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) to obtain the current working directory.

Comment: Are you sure that the file you are attempting to play is a valid WAVE file? Even if some players are able to play it properly, it could still be corrupt. You may want to exchange it with another WAVE file that was not created by the same program and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I am able to open the file using std::ifstream, and it open's perfectly,

Comment: Used a full path, in other words `L"S:\\Visual Studio Projects\\KB\\A\\Test.wav"`, still not functioning, and returning false,

Comment: The wave file plays perfectly through media players so I doubt it'd be invalid, asides from that I still tried alternate .wav files, still ran into the issue,

Comment: @IInspectable - "Using a relative path is always an error." - Oh yes? "Rel paths can be the source of errors" or "Rel paths often causes errors amongst those that don't realize how they work" - sure. Your assertion on the other hand.. Care to explain what you mean?

Comment: Enhzflep, agreed, I've never had an issue with relative paths, I was following working documentation for this code and they used relative paths aswell.

Comment: I tried that code with some wav file on my system. It works. I would look into that wav file, maybe it's not the proper format.

Comment: Thanks Adrian Roman! I suppose my wave files were not reading properly even though they could be read by other media software,

Comment: @enh The current working directory is process-global state. It is shared by all threads owned by that process, and any thread can change it at any time. You cannot build a reliable solution on top of a moving target.

Comment: @IInspectable - Thanks. Not quite what you said initially and the clarification is appreciated. Perhaps you should look into how to make sure the target doesn't move. Relative paths are both acceptable and easy to use.

Comment: @enh Relative paths are easy to use, but never acceptable. You cannot prevent the system or third party code from creating threads in your process. Thus, the current working directory must be assumed to be unpredictable. There is no valid use case for relative paths. If you need to access a resource relative to the filesystem location of some other entity, get a fully qualified path to that and construct the relative path from there.

Comment: @IInspectable - again, thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry! It's come to my attention all the WAVE files I was testing were for some reason invalid and unreadable, even though I could listen to them with other media software,

Comment: My guess is that your WAVE files are using a compressed format which is not supported by `PlaySound`. You could check this yourself by inspecting the headers of the WAVE file using a hex editor.